# How to convert a JavaScript array to a NSArray in Objective-C/iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, arrays

What's the best way to convert a JavaScript array (saved in an NSString) with this format:

```
["Hello", "World"]
```

in an NSArray?

Thanks

Comment: If it is valid JSON (which it is in this case), you can use a/the JSON parser. Are you sure the content can be any JavaScript (array), or will it actually be always JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I solved parsing the JSON/JS array, I posted the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
NSString * jsonString = @"[\"Hello\",\"World\"]";
NSError * serializationError = nil;
NSArray * array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&serializationError];
NSLog(@"NSArray - %@ \n error - %@", array, serializationError.localizedDescription);
```

Log:

NSArray - (
    Hello,
    World
) 
 error - (null)

Comment: Thanks, what is the meaning of the AllowFragments option?

Comment: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments - Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.

Comment: So does it mean that the parser can recognize the two objects of the array as strings and not as another array or dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

As Felix suggested, a JavaScript array is actually a JSON array.

So I solved doing some JSON parsing. Thank you!

```
NSError *e;
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:[arrayString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                              error:&e];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what your input string is, but you can use NSString's componentsSeparatedByString function to split up a string into an array of substrings.

Comment: Not what you want to do when you have `NSJSONSerialization`.